# Programmatically change logon wallpaper in win32, what is missing?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm trying to change the logon wallpaper in windows 8.1 from a win32 application, and seems that I'm missing some step, because in the "Lock screen settings" the image is showed as active, but when I lock the pc the image is not the one that I used.

Can someone explain-me what I'm missing to do?

The code is as following, and I'm using the CxxWinRTTemplate to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Concurrency;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;
using namespace Windows::System::UserProfile;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;

int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args) {

    if( args->Length != 2 ) {
        Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine(L"Invalid arguments.");
    } else {
        create_task(KnownFolders::PicturesLibrary->GetFileAsync(args[1])).then([](task<StorageFile^> getFileTask)
        {
            try {
                Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ file = getFileTask.get();
                create_task(LockScreen::SetImageFileAsync(file)).then([file](task<void> result)
                {
                    try {
                        // Use result.get() to trigger exception if invalid image is chosen
                        result.get();
                    } catch( Exception^ e ) {
                        Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
                    }
                }).wait();
            } catch( Exception^ e ) {
                Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine(e->Message);
            }
        }).wait();
    }return 0;
}
```

The image exists, and is a .jpg and has the same size of the primary desktop (and also the image size is smaller than 250kb, because in previous windows versions this was required, here I don't know...)

Thanks

Comment: This is not C++. Please specify the correct tags when posting questions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CX, it is an extension yes, but is c++